# How do we visualize data in hierarchical clustering?

Tags: clustering, visualization, dimensionality-reduction

Can anybody tell me how to do visualization when applying hierarchical clustering to data with more than 2 features? Do we need to do dimensionality reduction before each clustering?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two things without need.

A) visualizing hierarchical clustering, and

B) visualizing big dimensional data.

(B) is hard. If you solve (B) by some dimensionality reduction technique such as tSNE, then visualizing clusters (A) should be doable with standard methods.